# Open Angular Web Page app-root can't be found

Tags: angular

VS 2019, building an AspNet Core application including Angular project. Using ng build, the client app compiles without errors. But, when I navigate to the page I get an error that "app-root" did not match.

[image]

I've googled to no avail. Somebody help me with this, please!

Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information here to solve the problem. There is also no question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `index.html` does not have `app-root`.
Check your `index.html` has this element.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>   <!-- check your index.html has this line. -->
</body>
```